# NER using Stanford CoreNLP API through NLTK

Tags: python, nltk, stanford-nlp, named-entity-recognition

I'm trying to extract named entities using the Stanford CoreNLP API following [this example](https://github.com/nltk/nltk/wiki/Stanford-CoreNLP-API-in-NLTK).

```
from nltk.parse.corenlp import CoreNLPParser
ner_tagger = CoreNLPParser(url='http://localhost:9000', tagtype='ner')
list(ner_tagger.tag(('Rami Eid is studying at Stony Brook University in NY'.split())))
```

However, the code above throws the following error:

```
JSONDecodeError: Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes: line 16 column 25 (char 372)
```

Other API calls like parse are working just fine. I'm using the latest version (4.0.0) of Stanford CoreNLP.